# Why does my stringr function fail halfway through my dataset?

Tags: r, string, text

I am trying to extract dates from some character strings in a small (~13,000 obs) healthcare dataset for the purposes of text analysis.

Example data field called `Current Tracking Events`:

```
06/12/2019 Day 2: OPA with JK/MD. CT colonoscopy requested. | 17/12/2019 Day 13: CT colonoscopy:
```

There is often much more data than this separated by additional pipes |

I am using the following code:

```
extracted_data <- 
original data %>% 

  unnest_tokens(comment, `Current Tracking Events`, token = "regex", pattern = "[|]") %>% # to first divide the data by the piped sections

mutate(comment_date = str_detect(comment, pattern = "\\d+/\\d+/\\d+")) # extract the date at the start of the comment
```

This works for the first ~3,000 observations but then fails and returns NA.  When I extract some of the specific sets of observations where it has failed, it works again.  I don't know what other tests I can run to understand why it is not extracting the information I need.  Can anyone shed some light?  I have searched through Google and the documentation but can't see what might be going wrong.

The dataset has been imported into r from microsoft sql server using the odbc package.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file as a pipe-delimited file from the beginning instead:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_delim("path/to/your/file.psv", delim = "|")
```

This function will read all those rows that are correct and warn you about problems. You can see which rows were incorrect like so: `problems(df)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering!  I'm not sure this is going to work as I have a number of other fields in the dataset that I am pulling through from the sql server which are not delimited with a '|'.  I will keep working on this and see if I can find something that works.  I have now tried removing all non-UTF-8 characters from my strings, but it hasn't helped. It is very frustrating - when I extract a single row that has failed, the stringr function works again.

Comment: Quick update: if I divide my dataset into chunks of ~3000 rows, the function works.